# Split parameter in a texture atlas file?

Tags: java, libgdx, textures, texturepacker

How exactly works the `split` parameter in a `skin.atlas` file. `Libgdx` texture packer creates these from `9-patches` I believe. I need to manually add these sometimes (when using the texturepacker in the linked tag or when manually inserting/editing a texture) and cant seem to figure it out how they exactly work. Sometimes a single pixel makes my elements disappear or does not fill the split.

Here is a example files:

```
roundtext138.png
format: RGBA8888
filter: Nearest,Nearest
repeat: none
button
  rotate: false
  xy: 0, 0
  size: 46, 46
  split: 22, 22, 22, 22
  orig: 46, 46
  offset: 0, 0
  index: -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Libgdx texture packer should generate the split/padding parameters you see in the atlas from the metadata in the `.9.png` file.  Those numbers represent the `startX, endX, startY, endY` of the stretchable area (the middle section of the 9-element grid).  See [the source code](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/texturepacker/ImageProcessor.java#L272) that generates the `splits` array for more details.  (You can see the splits information being written out to the atlas [in TexturePacker.java](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/extensions/gdx-tools/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tools/texturepacker/TexturePacker.java#L326).)

Comment: Thanks. Im packing sometimes with a different tool that does not take 9 patches. And other times i paste elements in manually. I take its not possible to split the split so the center of a element will not stretch for some awesom button action :).

Comment: Also, endx is calculated from right end to right split right?

Answer (score 2):

I hope this image could solve your problems!

`a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` are the 4 parameters

[image: Split param visual info]