# How to create libgdx main menu screen

Tags: java, menu, libgdx

I'm new to java and libgdx and I want to create a main menu screen, Can someone give me a simple example?

Comment: As libgdx is more often used for game programming, you may get more answers by moving this question to the "Game Programming" Stack exchange.

Comment: Read about [Scene2d](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d) and [Scene2d skins](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/18/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-3-UI-Skins.aspx) and the come back with questions - although I'm sure you will be able to create menu after lecture

Answer (score 29, accepted):

What you are asking is very broad, it involves many elements like creating buttons, skins, setting up Tables, etc. Anyway you should use Screens for this, add a stage and add actors to the stage. Eventually you need to add Listeners to your button actors to switch screens. Here is one I made for you:

```
public class TestScreen implements Screen{

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    protected Stage stage;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    protected Skin skin;

    public TestScreen()
    {
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("skin.atlas");
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"), atlas);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(Constants.WorldWidth, Constants.WorldHeight, camera);
        viewport.apply();

        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();

        stage = new Stage(viewport, batch);    
    }


    @Override
    public void show() {
        //Stage should controll input:
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        //Create Table
        Table mainTable = new Table();
        //Set table to fill stage
        mainTable.setFillParent(true);
        //Set alignment of contents in the table.
        mainTable.top();

        //Create buttons
        TextButton playButton = new TextButton("Play", skin);
        TextButton optionsButton = new TextButton("Options", skin);
        TextButton exitButton = new TextButton("Exit", skin);

        //Add listeners to buttons
        playButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new PlayScreen());
            }
        });
        exitButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });

        //Add buttons to table
        mainTable.add(playButton);
        mainTable.row();
        mainTable.add(optionsButton);
        mainTable.row();
        mainTable.add(exitButton);

        //Add table to stage
        stage.addActor(mainTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.1f, .12f, .16f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        skin.dispose();
        atlas.dispose();
    }
}
```

The way I call this is by changing the initial class a bit.

```
//Let the class extend from game
public class MyGame extends Game()
{
    //Delete everything in it and leave a create() with a single line
    @Override
    public void create() {
    setScreen(new MenuScreen());
    }
}
```

Of course to make the above code work you need to setup a `Skin` and `Atlas` for drawing the buttons. You could however just add a image and a font and create your buttons manually. Anyway, I just [answered a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448088/how-do-i-make-textbuttons-using-libgdx/32452856#32452856) where I go in depth on creating a `Skin` and `Atlas`.

**Edit** Although an example of a menu class has been asked the user asker actually just needed to know how to switch from screen to screen. A bit awkward but luckely writing the above code just took a couple of minutes ;).

You can always access the `ApplicationListener` from anywhere using `Gdx.app.getApplicationListener`. You can cast this to `Game` to access `setScreen`.

```
((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new GameScreen());
```

Or you could pass along the initial Game object or applicationListener by hand. Make sure the new screen accepts the game object.

```
public class MenuScreen
{
    private Game gameObject;
    public MenuScreen(Game gameObject)
    {
        this.gameObject = gameObject;
    }
    private void someMethod()
    {
         //Switches to a new MenuScreen... 
         //useless in most cases but you get the idea
         gameObject.setScreen(new MenuScreen(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks sorry if you had to write all of the code but what I meant is just how to use multiple screens and switch screen, from my understanding when you click the button you setScreen(myOtherScreen()); but what is new Playscreen() ?? can't you just call the class of the other screen?

Comment: @StormAsdg Then next time be more specific ;). `setScreen` belongs to the Game object so either you have to call it from the stored applicationListener or pass the initial `Game` object allong.
You do `((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(nextScreen);` Or you could pass the initial Game object allong and do `gameObject.setScreen`.

Comment: Keep in mind that wehn using `setScreen(new GameScreen());` you are creating a new screen everytime and if you do not load the current state it will be reset to default. This is not a problem if you load the state in the Screen itself. Like the slider values for music and sound in an options screen. But you need to use a AssetManager for your assets otherwise things will slow down pretty fast.

Comment: So ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new PlayScreen()); you basically created a screen named PlayScreen, does it switch to another screen? I'm confused cause you just created a new one without any reference from other classes that implements screen. How do you call the other screen and render them

Comment: @StormAsdg What you mean? You need to create a `PlayScreen` class like in the same way you create `MenuScreen`.

Comment: @StormAsdg If you wish we could continue this in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89051/libgdx-screen-management

Comment: So you basically called the PlayScreen class and created a screen at the same time? PlayScreen() is a class just like MenuScreen and TestScreen

Comment: @StormAsdg No I set the screen to a new object of class `PlayScreen`. Like you say `PlayScreen` would be a class. With the `new` keyword I create an object from that class. It's the same as. `PlayScreen playScreen = new PlayScreen();` and then `setScreen(playScreen);`

Comment: @StormAsdg `setScreen` just needs to be supplied with a object that implements `Screen`. How you do that is your choice. If you have more questions about this or screen management let's take it to the chat I posted above.

Comment: Ohh now I understand it's basically initializing an object for that class then calling it. thanks