# Libgdx Scene2dUi and Viewport

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport, scene2d

I have made my layout in scene 2d and implemented it. But the sizing is the issue. It comes in different alignment for my android phone and on desktop.

Although I think that the solution is to use viewport but I don't know how to correctly implement it.

The way I am implementing it gives me a white screen

```
 @Override
  public void show() {
    width=GameScreen.getGameWidth();
    height=GameScreen.getGameHeight();
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true,width ,height);

    stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(width, height,camera)); 

    parameter.size = 40;
    parameter.color=Color.WHITE;
    parameter.flip=false;
    font12 = generator.generateFont(parameter); // font size 12 pixels
    generator.dispose();

    TextureAtlas atlas= new TextureAtlas(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiAtlas.atlas"));
    skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/uiskin.json"));
    skin2= new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/achievementSkin.json"),atlas);
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

    mainTable = new Table();
    levelTable = new Table();

    stage.addActor(mainTable);
    mainTable.setFillParent(true);

    scrollPane = new ScrollPane(levelTable, skin);
    scrollPane.setFlickScroll(true);
    scrollPane.setFadeScrollBars(true);

    labelStyle=new LabelStyle();
    labelStyle.font=font12;

    makeLevelMenu();
}



public void makeLevelMenu() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        columnTable.add(new Table());

        // Image
        button.add(new ImageButton(skin2, "playButton"));
        columnTable.get(i).add(button.get(i)).colspan(2).padBottom(100)
                .padLeft(100).padRight(100).padTop(100);

        columnTable.get(i).row();
        // Enemy Label
        enemyLabel.add(new Label("Enemy " + (i + 1), labelStyle));
        columnTable.get(i).add(enemyLabel.get(i)).left().padBottom(300)
                .padTop(100);

        columnTable.get(i).row();
        // Battle Style
        battleStyle.add(new Label("Battle Style " + (i + 1), labelStyle));
        columnTable.get(i).add(battleStyle.get(i)).left().padBottom(100);

        levelTable.add(columnTable.get(i)).expand();
    }
    levelTable.debug();
    // achievementsTable.setFillParent(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < button.size(); i++) {
        final int k = i;
        button.get(k).addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {
                System.out.println("Level " + (k + 1) + "touchDown");
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y,
                    int pointer, int button) {

            }
        });
    }
    scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(false, false);
    mainTable.add(scrollPane).expand().fill();
}



@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.gl20.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    stage.act(delta);
    stage.draw();
}

@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
    stage.getViewport().update(width, height, true);
}
```

Comment: can you provide your **render()** Screen method?

Comment: ya sure . i have editted the qs.

Comment: both the answers from below work!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX indeed offers `Vieworts` to help you with different resolutions. Personally I mostly use `FitViewport`, it keep the aspect ratio and "black" boxes the rest. There are a number of other viewports such as StretchViewport which does exactly what you expect.

You can easily test what fits your game if you setup everything correctly. [The following code is straight from www.gamesfromscratch.com](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-17-Viewports.aspx). And they describe the behavior of the less obvious viewports.

```
public class ViewportDemo extends ApplicationAdapter {
   SpriteBatch batch;
   Sprite aspectRatios;
   OrthographicCamera camera;
   Viewport viewport;

   @Override
   public void create () {
      batch = new SpriteBatch();
      aspectRatios = new Sprite(new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("Aspect.jpg")));
      aspectRatios.setPosition(0,0);
      aspectRatios.setSize(100,100);

      camera = new OrthographicCamera();
      viewport = new FillViewport(100,100,camera);
      viewport.apply();

      camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
   }

   @Override
   public void render () {

      camera.update();
      Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1);
      Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

      batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
      batch.begin();
      aspectRatios.draw(batch);
      batch.end();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose(){
      aspectRatios.getTexture().dispose();
   }

   @Override
   public void resize(int width, int height){
      viewport.update(width,height);
      camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2,camera.viewportHeight/2,0);
   }
```

You could do this yourself. Create any image, stick it to the stage and play with the different viewports and screen size. Also forget working with pixels since a pixel is a hardware thing.

**Edit**

The above implementation from www.gamesfromscratch.com does not show how to use the implementation in a stage. However this is as simple as it gets.

```
stage = new Stage(viewport, batch);
```

Now the stage will use the viewport and batch you provided. Now simply add stuff to the stage and draw it like you would do normally.

The following is my code that creates a very basic menu screen using a stage and a fitviewport. You do need your own atlas and skin to make this work, [check my answer here on SO to learn more about that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32448088/how-do-i-make-textbuttons-using-libgdx/32452856#32452856)

```
public class MenuScreen implements Screen{

    private SpriteBatch batch;
    protected Stage stage;
    private Viewport viewport;
    private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private TextureAtlas atlas;
    protected Skin skin;

    public MenuScreen()
    {
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("atlas.txt");
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("skin.json"), atlas);

        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        viewport = new FitViewport(RealmOfConflict.WorldWidth, RealmOfConflict.WorldHeight, camera);
        viewport.apply();

        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();

        stage = new Stage(viewport, batch);

        //Stage should controll input:
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }    

    @Override
    public void show() {
        //Create Table
        Table mainTable = new Table();
        //Set table to fill stage
        mainTable.setFillParent(true);
        //Set alignment of contents in the table.
        mainTable.top();

        //Create buttons
        TextButton playButton = new TextButton("Play", skin);
        TextButton optionsButton = new TextButton("Options", skin);
        TextButton exitButton = new TextButton("Exit", skin);

        //Add listeners to buttons
        playButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                ((Game)Gdx.app.getApplicationListener()).setScreen(new PlayScreen());
            }
        });
        exitButton.addListener(new ClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });

        //Add buttons to table
        mainTable.add(playButton);
        mainTable.row();
        mainTable.add(optionsButton);
        mainTable.row();
        mainTable.add(exitButton);

        //Add table to stage
        stage.addActor(mainTable);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(.1f, .12f, .16f, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        stage.act();
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height);
        camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2, camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
        camera.update();
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void hide() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        skin.dispose();
        atlas.dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: actually I don't have any problems using it with batcher 'cause i am already doing ti. But the problem lies only when I use stage.

Comment: You are asking for a vieport implementation if I read correctly, well this is how you do it. Stage takes a `Viewport` and `Batch` in the constructor so simply do `stage = new Stage(yourViewport, batch);` and it should work. If you keep having problems, try a smaller program with like a single table with a single image or button on the stage. If you got that working play with it till you understand better.

Comment: If you will look at my code you will find out that it is mentioned for stage. And yes I have tried your thing also. may be I will go with advice of doing it little at a time

Comment: The code I supplied is for a stage. I always use this... `(Stage stage = new Stage(viewport, batch)` and you stage will be using the viewport as it's "canvas".

Comment: Forget the batch in the render method of the code I supplied. It's just a copy from www.gamesfromscratch.com. Just add the viewport and batch to the stage and just draw the stage in `render()` like `stage.draw()`.

Comment: So how should I implement this. I will make viewport like yours along with camera and then i will add a batcher to my stage initialization. then in render hust act and draw stage .

Comment: I will make an edit for you with my own code in a couple of minutes ;).

Comment: thanks man your solution is working. but I am in a kind of fix on which answer to accept 'cause both works.

Comment: @uday Take a look at that edit and you might get a bit more insight. I bet your problem was that you did not call `stage.draw()`.

Comment: not exactly but something along that line. i just refactored my code and cleaned it and then minimised it and then tried your solution. before it was hoch poch. thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the viewport's camera. You are creating your own camera and don't setting its position and not updateing it.

If there is no reason to create your own camera just lean on default stage camera. Instead of:

```
    camera = new OrthographicCamera();
    camera.setToOrtho(true,width ,height);

    stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(width, height,camera));
```

use

```
    //no camera defining
    stage = new Stage(new FillViewport(width, height));
```

and then normal flow of your app

Comment: okay lemme try but i have done the same thing before and its showing a white screen.

Comment: try also fill all actors before adding it to stage

Comment: ya I tried it. But unfortunately the white screen comes up again!!

Comment: how to use fill actors

Comment: I don't mean *fill* like doing something special - just move adding them to the stage at the very end of show() method when they are totaly set. For example you have **stage.addActor(mainTable);** but you are adding the scroll to the mainTable later.

Comment: will it work fine if i add main table to my stage after calling make level menu.

Comment: i did that. after make level menu  i added main table to my stage but still that dreaded white screen.